# A nest of wild rabbits pretty much live in our backyard. Can we get a hutch for them?

Tags: rabbits

There is a group of wild rabbits who hang around in my girlfriend's backyard all the time. Her mom leaves out lettuce and such so that's probably what attracted them.

They recently had baby bunnies and over time they've become quite endearing to us. We really want to provide food and shelter for them. Especially now that there is so much rain here in the East coast. Neither of us have the time (or expertise) to build something good for them so I was hoping to get a large hutch off of Amazon that has multiple entry/exit points (for them to escape when needed).

The two ones I found that have possible escape routes are these:

[First choice option as it seems safer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FN3ZVTY)

[Second choice one due to price and reviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DE6KQUG)

We really want to keep them in our backyard because they mean a lot to us and we want to provide proper shelter for them.

I really don't know much about rabbits so any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: With the hutches in mind, will they be able to go in and out freely? Or be kept in an enclosed area?

Comment: If you want to lock them in a hutch this is a duplicate of the existing question [Can I make a baby wild rabbit a pet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/854/can-i-make-a-baby-wild-rabbit-a-pet) if you want them to remain wild and just provide shelter the question is borderline on/off topic.  For general questions about [rabbits in hutches see these posts](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits+containment)

Comment: Wild rabbits build their own barrows and have dealt with rain for centuries. If you don't want to domesticate them, let them live their natural way. Spoiling them by providing food and shelter might put them in a tough situation if they get dependant on it and you cannot provide for them any longer one day.