# Can I keep a baby wild rabbit as a pet

Tags: rabbits

My dog brought us a baby wild bunny about a week ago and luckily, the little guy has survived. It's a small cotton tail and its around 3-4 weeks old according to the vet. I've asked on their advice in whether to keep it or release it and the vets said that it will be hard as she’ll likely lose her instincts and might not survive once released.

I don't know what to do with the situation. I could keep it as I do have enough space and I'm willing to take care of it, but I also know these animals are not meant to be kept like this. I just want what's best for the little guy.

Comment: Hi, I found a question which is similar to yours, I think you could find valuable answers there. Please take a look at this: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/854/can-i-make-a-baby-wild-rabbit-a-pet and hope it helps. Best wishes for the poor, fluffy soul.